# Java: Input a file to a process

Tags: java

I am writing a simple Java project call Robot. The Robot can accept a config file from the command prompt (If there is not file, the robot will use the default config) by:

```
java Robot < config.txt
```

Does anyone know how I can read the redirect input from the command prompt in java?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can access `System.in` as an input stream, that will contain all redirected input.

Specifically, reading from a redirected stdin is the same as reading from the regular stdin.

For example, let's say you want to read a list of integers from a redirected stream.

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.IOException;
public class Foo {
    public static void main(String args[])
        throws IOException
    {
        BufferedReader r = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        int sum = 0;
        String line;
        while ((line = r.readLine()) != null) {
            sum += Integer.parseInt(line);
        }
        System.out.println(sum);
    }
}
```

Then when you run this, you'll get

```
$ (echo 1; echo 2; echo 65) > foo.txt
$ java Foo < foo.txt
68
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply but can you be more specific?

Comment: Cool! Thanks. I tried it and it works. However, after the Robot finish reading the config file, it will prompt to an interactive mode. I tried to another while loop after the while loop that you added but the bufferedReader returns me null. Can you give me some direction?

Comment: @Kintarō What do you mean that it "will prompt to an interactive mode"?  Do you mean that after it reads the config file, you would like to interact with the program from the command line?

Comment: Yes. I would like to read it from the config file and then I can interact it from the command line. If there is no config file, I can directly access to the command line.